# Incompatible bit masks in findBug intellij

Tags: java, intellij-idea, findbugs, clover

I am running findbugs on the below code it giving me below error

Incompatible bit masks
This method compares an expression of the form (e | C) to D. which will always compare unequal due to the specific values of constants C and D. This may indicate a logic error or typo.
Typically, this bug occurs because the code wants to perform a membership test in a bit set, but uses the bitwise OR operator ("|") instead of bitwise AND ("&").

```
  if (!conditionplace.isEmpty()) 
   {
           for (Place place : conditionplace) {
            parent.writeWithModificationType(
                condId,
                place.getId(),
                place.getDisplay()

            );
        }
    }
```

I am also using clover for my test coverage

Can anyone help me to fix this ?

Answer (score 1):

The error you're getting is strictly related to how Clover works. It instruments every single line of your code to record its execution. When it instruments branch conditions it adds additional conditions to record *true branch execution* in such way that logical condition remains unchanged. So in your case it will do something like this

```
if (
(!conditionplace.isEmpty()) &&    (__CLR4_2_000ito7x4bh.R.iget(9)!=0|true) // if true
|| 
(__CLR4_2_000ito7x4bh.R.iget(10)==0&false) //else
) {
//code
```

It uses non-circuit operators to make sure its code is executed and it's able to record execution of all expressions in the condition (there may be plenty of them).

Generally speaking, Clover adds plenty of weird, machine generated code (you can instrument Java class and see the result) thus it's not really recommended to run any kind of static code analysis on instrumented source code.